# Create timed medications in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

In `R` I have panel data by `UserID`. I also have the `time` they took medicine `A, B, or C`.

```
UserID   Time Medicine
1 9925    11  Med A
2 9925    36  Med B
3 9925    52  Med A
4 966     14  Med A
5 966     59  Med C
6 949     10  Med A
```

A user could took A then B or perhaps A then C. Many possible combinations. I need to create a conditional probability table such that if they took A first what is the probability they took C next? I was think about creating another set of variable `First.Med`, `Second.Med`, `Third.Med`, but that seems challenging as well. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no A, B or C in your data.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I'm trying to figure out how to say by UserID select the min(Time) and display Medicine. Once I have that I could filter by the same process, repeating until I have first, second and third purchase columns.

Comment: @PDog Any attempt to convert this logic into code ?

Comment: So I can get the minimum time by User via `min <-aggregate(data.df[ , c("Time",)], list(data.df$UserID) , min)` , but I can't drag the corresponding Medicine with it. I could then match this with the original DF, but it's a partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to collapse `Medicine` by `UserID` and run `prop.table` on the collapsed string.  This will give the proportion of every combination - if you want to look at only certain combinations then you can subset easily from there.

```
mydf <- read.table(text="UserID Time Medicine
1 9925    11  'Med A'
2 9925    36  'Med B'
3 9925    52  'Med A'
4 966     14  'Med A'
5 966     59  'Med C'
6 949     10  'Med A'", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mydf$Medicine <- sub("Med ", "", mydf$Medicine)
mydf <- mydf[order(mydf$UserID, mydf$Time),]
medcol <- aggregate(Medicine ~ UserID, mydf, paste, collapse="")[2]

prop.table(table(medcol))

    A       ABA        AC 
0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
```